# React js is showing component export error in the render

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I need to export my react table component, when i export it normally it says the following error:

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `Dashboard`.
```

My table component is :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactTable from "react-table";

class Pacifyr extends Component {
  
  render() {
    const data = [{
      name: 'Roy Agasthyan',
      age: 26
    },{
      name: 'Sam Thomason',
      age: 22
    },{
      name: 'Michael Jackson',
      age: 36
    },{
      name: 'Samuel Roy',
      age: 56
    },{
      name: 'Rima Soy',
      age: 28
    },{
      name: 'Suzi Eliamma',
      age: 28
    }]

    const columns = [{
      Header: 'Name',
      accessor: 'name'
    },{
      Header: 'Age',
      accessor: 'age'
    }]

    return (
          <div>
              <ReactTable
                data={data}
                columns={columns}
                defaultPageSize = {3}
                pageSizeOptions = {[3, 6]}
              />
          </div>      
    )

  }
}

export default Pacifyr;
```

My app.js :

```
import Pacifyr from './components/table';
<Route exact path="/pacifyr" component={Pacifyr} />
```

How to rectify this error?

I need to use react table with search and sort option and also it shows export error.

Comment: The error states `Check the render method of Dashboard.` Is that a different component elsewhere in the app?

Comment: Dashboard and pacifyr are same only, i changed the export name from dashboard to pacifyr

Comment: Can you share an screen grab of your directory structure?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that you are wrong on importing and implementing the react table. React Table is a hook library, not a component library. you can checkout the example's [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/master/examples/basic)

Comment: OP is using a class component instead of functional component so looks won't be able to use hooks unless he refactors

Comment: @Hyetigran yes, he need to refactor his component if he were to use react table, maybe he was using old version of react-table?